# Huge gap in Magento dashboard vs Google Analytics revenue

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, google-analytics

I am running Magento 1.7.0.2. There seems to be a huge difference in what the Magento dashboard reports and Google Analytics reports in terms of revenue.

Google Analytics is showing that the revenue is about 33% higher than what it says on Magento. There doesn't seem to be duplicate orders coming up in Google Analytics. Even if I subtract tax and shipping from Google's revenue - it is still much higher than Magento's reporting. Has anyone noticed/experienced this issue?

Comment: There are a lot of options here and I would suggest comparing a given range one by one to work out where the higher values are coming from. Some things that come to mind 1) account number is used on other sites  (like your test/staging site) 2) different currencies 3) different time zone settings - effectively making you compare different times

Comment: Google Analytics records all incoming sales, Magento removes all cancelled sales. The discrepancy grows over time. Google Analytics is only an indicator of activity, not a record of your successful sales. In the sales department, you're going to find that Google Analytics is an Ego Massager and Soul Salve. While it has a lot of useful features for everything else, **it is not a reliable accounting system**.

Comment: It also doesn't track reduction in revenue via issued credit memos.

Comment: Glad to do that, I've had to explain it to management several times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Analytics records all incoming sales, Magento removes all cancelled sales.

The discrepancy between Magento reported sales and Google Analytics e-commerce sales grows over time.

Google Analytics is only an indicator of activity, not a record of your successful sales. In the sales department, you're going to find that Google Analytics is an Ego Massager and Soul Salve.

While Google Analytics has a lot of useful features for everything else, it is not a reliable accounting system for tracking the website financials.

It also doesn't track reduction in revenue via issued credit memos or any other transactions done in the Admin backend..

Answer (score 1):

The reports in Magento are broken and dont show correct numbers.

Several People I know looked further into the reports and noticed some strong discrepancies regarding the numbers to real revenue and other values.

To keep it simple, you cant relay on the numbers the reports of Magento gives you.

Comment: Neither Magento, nor Google Analytics are accounting packages and Magento falls so far short of GAAP rules that it is not to be trusted for either inventory or sales/revenue tracking. Your ERP internal accounting package gives you the true numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so both Magento and Google Analytics give reporting errors. Therefore both aren't going to much up as their reporting errors are different.

Also people are right GA only does topline sales whilst Magento does takes into account refunds.

I actually wrote an article on this. Here is a link:

https://blog.mocoinsight.com/2014/03/25/google-analytics-vs-magento-reporting/

Gives you more info on why they don't match up.